# No data in location returned from URLSession(session:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL location)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using a standards background session for handing a background fetch. The operations starts fine and callback:

```
URLSession(session:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL location)
```

is regularly called, yet when I check the contents of the location url I find nil. I checked the url being processed and it was the good one, and when submitted on a browser correctly returns data. What might it be? I know I need to copy the data as it is in a temporary cache, but I checked its contents immediately when it should still be there. This is my code:

```
let span:Float=0.005
func handleRemoteFetch(completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)?){
    fetchCompletion=completionHandler;
    fetchInitiation={[unowned self] in
        let theRequest=mapDelegate.sharedMapDelegate().requestForRefreshAndLocation(self.presentLocation!, span:self.span)
        let task = self.backgroundSession.downloadTaskWithRequest(theRequest)
        task.resume()
        print(theRequest.description)
    }
    if (presentLocation != nil){
        fetchInitiation!()
        fetchInitiation=nil
    }
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
    downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
    didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){
        print(downloadTask.originalRequest!.description)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
        if data != nil {
            let str = String(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(str);
        } else {
            print("empty output")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue did not present itself when the app executed on a physical device. After some time it also started working on the simulator for no compelling reason.

Comment: just to add a comment for future visitors, I think what he said above is key: "I checked its contents immediately when it should still be there." For me, I was checking the content of the NSURL after 10 mines of code, and half the time it wasn't there, because it is a temporary URL and was already erased from memory. Be sure to get the contents of the NSURL immediately after download finishes first thing in order to know it won't return nil.